# Load WebView with Variable

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsstring, nsurlrequest

I am trying to accomplish a very simple task of loading a WebView that has a variable. I am hoping to pass the variable from objective-c to a remote PHP file. The code I am using does not seem to work. The variable is valid, but I cannot get it to pass to the PHP file to be read by the WebView. Any help would be great!

```
    NSString *userId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"userId"];

[webViewFirst loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?userId=%@",userId]]];
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `+[NSString stringWithFormat]` to build the URL string:

```
NSString *userId = <#whatever#>;
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?userId=%@", userId]
[webViewFirst loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
```

Comment: Wow. tremendous help!!!! I will mark your answer as accepted (says I need to wait 2 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

NSURL URLWithString does not support string formatting, so you cannot use it like you are trying to do.

What happens, instead, is that the C `,` operator is used, which just sequences the two expressions: `@"http://www.website.com/page.php?userId=%@"` and `userId`, and evaluates to the last one.

Use `stringWithFormat` to get it right:

```
[webViewFirst loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?userId=%@",userId]]]];
```